# Validate media objects in PHP

Tags: php, media, validation

I want to allow users on my website to link to remote media objects: flash, music, movies, etc. I already have a regex to check for links:

```
/(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;\/~\+#])?/i
```

With the matched links, I want to check if they are media files instead of just checking for the the extension on the URL. I was thinking that I could just check the the HTTP headers for the content-type, but that might be a little too much—I was hoping that PHP might have some native functions already.

Comment: Just so it's said: Unless you control the server where the file is hosted, this tactic won't help much.  I can host a site that provides a blank movie or something when you're checking for links, and switch it out whenever i please to whatever i want.  Unless you're constantly and repeatedly checking links, you won't catch that.

Comment: It's meant to load on user profiles like MySpace—if they can do it then I'm sure there's a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [FileInfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.fileinfo.php) extension provides the [`finfo_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) function, which will give you the mimetype of a file.

From its introduction manual page:

> The functions in this module try to guess the content type and encoding of a file by looking for certain magic byte sequences at specific positions within the file. While this is not a bullet proof approach the heuristics used do a very good job.

Comment: Note: before PHP 5.3.0 you would use `mime_content_type` or had to install fileinfo from PECL